# User Auth Failure

Tags: users, authentication

I was trying to change my usernme on Ubuntu 12.04 lts by opening Terminal and enter this command

```
$ sudo nautilus
```

Then, I went to

```
File System > home > alex (my username)
```

I right click on alex folder and rename it. When I restart my computer, I cannot login as Administartor

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot from a LiveCD/USB and choose "Try Ubuntu".
2. Open a terminal and run `sudo -H nautilus`.
3. Undo your rename change.

Comment: How to Boot from a USB?

Comment: @ScriptKiddies: How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: From a USB of course

Comment: There is no "of course" when installing Linux. There are tens of different methods for installing Ubuntu. Live CD/USB mentioned above is the USB you used for installation. You are specifically asked how you installed it because you did not seem to know what a Live CD/USB is.

Comment: Yes, I used USB to install Ubuntu. I make the USB bootable.

Comment: @ScriptKiddies: Then do the same again, except this time, select "Try Ubuntu".

Comment: @minerz029 , Alright. Thanks a lot. Will try it later

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You can not change your username by just changing the Home folder name. Not even sure you can change your username once it is created, other than making a new user with the desired name, copy the content from former user's Home folder into your new one, and then deleting the former user and it's folder.

But as minerz029 said. Boot a live DVD/USB and fix your folder name. Otherwise you will be stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an usb, you can do it by dropping to root shell from the recovery menu.

1. At boot time hold down right shift key, to enter grub menu.
2. Select recovery mode (second boot option).
3. You will drop to a menu after boot. Select Filesystem Check to mount your fs to read-write, the easy way.
4. Select drop to root shell, to gain root access.
5. Rename your home folder: `mv /home/Administrator /home/alex`
6. do a `reboot`

**Picture:**
[image]